# MVC .NET Form Submission not hitting Controller Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form to create an object in a view as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Request", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RequestDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Requester)
    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-5">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mui-select">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, "Key", "Value"))
                <label>Category</label>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Requester, new { disable = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
                <label>Requester</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestDate, new { @id = "txtRequestDate" })
                <label>Request Date</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mui-select">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentRequestId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Requests, "Key", "Value"))
                <label>Parent Request</label>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentRequestId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-5" style="float:right;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mui-select">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Destination, "Select Destination Site...", new { type = "text" })
                <label>Destination Site</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ETDDate, new { @id = "txtETDDate" })
                <label>ETD Date</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mui-select">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.ReasonCode, "Select Reason...", new { type = "text" })
                <label>Reason Code</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reason, null)
                <label>Reason</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

As you can see this should hit `/Request/Create` as a POST request.

I have a button outside the form as such:

```
<li id="new-menu" class="top-level">
    <a href="#" id="saveBtn">Save</a>
</li>
```

and this submits via jquery:

```
$('#saveBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#createForm').submit();
});
```

My controller method in `RequestController` is:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Request request)
{
    //DO STUFF
    return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { id = request.Id });
}
```

However putting a breakpoint on the first line of this method, doesnt give me anything as it is not hitting the action.

I have checked out the call in the Network tab of Developer Tools and the body of the request is fine, it has picked up all of the detail correctly so it matches the `Request` object that the action is expecting. It also returns a `200` response code but nothing in the Response itself.

I am unsure how to debug this further and find the actual issue.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Many Thanks in Advance :)

** EDIT **

To clarify, my response from this is a blank page in the browser but obviously I know its not hitting the controller using breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK So I have worked this out and will post the answer here in case it helps others:

In my `Request` model, i had a field called Value with a getter as below:

```
[NotMapped]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public decimal Value
{
    get
    {
        return Lines.Sum(l => l.Value);
     }
}
```

However, at the time of creation, a request does not have any lines so this was failing.

Therefore changing it to the below fixes the issue by giving it a default value in a sense:

```
[NotMapped]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public decimal Value
{
    get
    {
        return Lines != null && Lines.Count() > 0 ? Lines.Sum(l => l.Value) : 0;
    }
}
```